# How to display a pandas dataframe on a Stack Overflow question body

Tags: discussion, code-formatting, formatting

I need to display a pandas dataframe in a Stack Overflow question body. I have already tried to display copying and pasting in a block of code but got completely unreadable.

This is result I got:

```
                             id                            text  top_class  class_name  confidence
8988   20809_451291030_17944026    ainda nao recebi minha senha       1001        1001    0.976569
8989   20810_459751030_18018215    ainda nao recebi minha senha       1001        1001    0.976569
9009   20810_455341030_17968671        ainda nao recebi a senha       1001        1001    0.971450
9010   20810_455341030_17968671        ainda nao recebi a senha       1001       14008    0.011035
9011   20809_458715030_18010104        ainda nao recebi a senha       1001        1001    0.971450
```

I want to display my dataframe similar to the following.

> [image: Picture of the desired output]

How can I achieve this result on a question?

Comment: That actually looks pretty good to me.

Comment: Do you wish to have the headers included or is the current behavior of no headers correct?

Comment: thanks for your time @QuangHoang and @Spencer Stream, yes i wanted the headers to be display also, and i could achive the desire result using language identifier on my block of code ```python

```

Answer (score -2):

You can include the dataframe as a markdown table:

```python
print(df.to_markdown())
```

And then answerers can ingest it directly with pandas:

```python
df = pd.read_html('https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/391900')[0]
```